# Wordpress Shortcode: Causing page editor to autoload preview

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode

Very odd issue I am having. I add the following code to just add a test shortcode to my Wordpress functions.php.

```
//TEST SHORTCODE
add_shortcode( 'sc_brandon_test', 'brandon_test' );
function brandon_test(){
echo 'Brandon\'s Test Shortcode file works correctly!';
}
```

When using the shortcode [sc_brandon_test] in the editor the page will auto-redirect to a broken preview of the page I am trying to edit.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don't echo your shortcode output directly but use a return.
`echo` would output your content immediately.

The desired behaviour is to parse the shortcode output within your main content loop e.g calling `the_content()` or
`apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));`

```
add_shortcode( 'sc_brandon_test', 'brandon_test' );
function brandon_test(){
   $output = 'Brandon\'s Test Shortcode file works correctly!';
   return $output;
}
```

I recommend these guides
[WordPress  Scholar: WordPress Shortcodes](https://wpscholar.com/presentations/wordpress-shortcodes/)
[smashing magazine: WordPress Shortcodes: A Complete Guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/)

Comment: That does fix my errors thank you!

Comment: I am creating the shortcodes to pull in custom forms as needed, is there a good way to do something with that amount of code vs a simple line of text? When just adding the php code it seemed easy but having to save it to an output makes it seem a bit more complicated.

Comment: I guess it depends on the complexity of your form code you want to output. You might check the code of available form plugins – contact form 7 might be interesting as it's not too bloated (so it's plugin code might be comprehensible). Probably you should start a new thread with php examples you'd like to render – forms can be really tricky